# How to use splice on a string js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, performance

I have noticed that there is no direct solution but also I can think of at least two ways of implementing it.

What I'd like to know what is the best solution performance-wise?

- Turn a string into and array, use splice, return to string
- Use string s = s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i,s.lenght)
- Something I've missed

EDIT: What's wrong with my question and is there some faster way to do this? I want to do this around a tousand times on a string so I need it to be fast

Comment: http://jsperf.com and substrings should be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

I runned it on a [JSPERF](http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-substring2) and substrings is a little bit faster then doing a splice !

Edit:

substring is pretty fast, my computer ran this function:

```
var str = "I love cookies"
str = str.substring(0, 1) + " really" + str.substring(1);
```

756 333 times in 0.053 secondes !

Answer (score 0):

### Here's a nice little Curry which you may want to benchmark.

#### I think its about as simple as it will get.

The second function's signature is identical to the `Array.prototype.splice` method.

```
function mutate(s) {
    return function splice() {
        var a = s.split('');
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(a, arguments);
        return a.join('');
    };
}

mutate('101')(1, 1, '1');
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!